# Rieman integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

For this question, I think I need to use the fact that this function is continuous. But, how do I know that?

> Let $f$ be the function on $[0,1]$ given by
>   $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
> 0, & 0 \le x < 1\\
> 1, & 1 \le x < 2\\
> 2, & 2 \le x < 3\\
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> 1. Prove that $f$ is Riemann integrable without appealing to any theorems in this section
> 2. Which theorems in this section guarantee that $f$ is Riemann integrable?
> 3. What is $\int_0^3 f(x) dx$?

Also, how is it possible to prove that this function is Riemann integrable without using any theorems.

Using that the function is continuous, we could say $U_p(f)-L_p(f) \le \epsilon$ just by saying $|x_n-x_{n-1}|\le \epsilon/3$. And, how do we calculate the integral of it? Is $U_p(f)- L_p(f)$ equal to the integral of f?

Thank you

P.S: Every bounded monotone function on a closed interval is Riemann integrable according to the theorem. I cannot find a theorem to show that this function is Riemann integrable because I am not so sure that this function is monotone. Is it monotone increasing?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip. I will use that in the future for sure.

Comment: You can't show that $f$ is continuous because it's obviously not.

Comment: then how will I show it is riemann integrable?

Comment: The source is Reed, B.C. _Fundamental Ideas of Analysis_ (1998) p. 111

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

It is easier to handle if you say that
$$
\int_0^3 f(x)dx = \int_0^1 f(x)dx + \int_1^2 f(x)dx + \int_2^3 f(x)dx
$$
and then $f$ is continuous on each interval of integration.

As for your second question, I am not sure about your notation, but it seems, given a partition $P(n)$ of $[a,b]$ you have
$$
L_{P(n)}(f) \le \int_a^b f(x) dx \le U_{P(n)}(f)
$$
so if the function is integrable, you end up with
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} L_{P(n)}(f) = \int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} 
 U_{P(n)}(f)
$$

Comment: But that's using a theorem! Namely the theorem that if $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ and on $[b,c]$ then it is Riemann integrable on $[a,c]$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich it only forbids "theorems in this section" -- not sure if this one is included

Comment: what if we divide the function into partition P= x0, x1, x2, x3, where x0=0, x1= 1, x2=2 x3=3. Lp(f) on this partition is 4.And Up(f) is 4 as well. Their difference is zero. But the epsilon is greater zero so Up(f)-Lp(f) less than epsilon, which proves the function is riemann integrable. What do you think about this way?

Comment: @bebe it is Riemann integrable when the limit of your mesh becomes the integration interval

Comment: @gt6989b Ok then I found a different way. Lets say P = {x0,x1, ..., xN, xN+1,..,xM). and max(xi-xi-1)<ϵ/3. Then Up(f)-Lp(f)<ϵ after some calculation. but I am having problem with finding a theorem to prove that this function f(x) is Riemann integrable. Because I dont know whether it is monotone or not. Is it monotone?

Comment: @bebe *monotone* means non-decreasing or non-increasing -- looks like non-decreasing to me

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to use the definition of Riemann Integral and try to calculate 
$$\sup\{L(f,P):\ P\text{ is a partition of }[0,3]\}$$
and
$$\inf\{U(f,P):\ P\text{ is a partition of }[0,3]\}.$$

I guess that any upper and lower rieman sum will be always the same number, namely, the intergal.

EDIT: at least, you always can add the discontinuity point to your partition to get always the same number. Just an idea.

EDIT2:
Let $P$ be any partition of $[0,3]$. Let $P_0:=P\cup\{1,2\}$. It is clear that $P_0$ is finer than $P$, hence $U(f,P)\ge U(f,P_0)$. But a simple calculation says that $U(f,P_0)=3=\int_0^3 f(x)dx$.

So $$3\le \inf\{U(f,P):\ P\text{ is a partition of }[0,3]\}\le U(f,\{0,1,2,3\})=3.$$

Analogously, you work with $L(f,P)$ and you are done.
It is very easy to get the other inequality