# Continuous function with 2 discontinuous points is Riemann integrable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

> Suppose that $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous except at $r_1,r_2\in(a,b)$. Prove that $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

Intuitively, I know this is true because the upper sum and lower sum will only differ by the contribution from $f(r_1)$ and $f(r_2)$, and you refine the partition until it disappears. But I'm not quite sure how to turn that into a formal proof.

Comment: MAybe you can do it in a similar way that I do in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980279/rieman-integration/2980811#2980811

Comment: You also need to assume that $g$ is bounded on $[a, b]$. The result can be easily generalized: *if the function $g:[a, b]\to\mathbb {R} $ is bounded on $[a, b] $ and if the set $D$ of its discontinuities on $[a, b] $ has a finite number of limit points then $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$*.

Comment: The crux of the argument is to show that a single discontinuity does not matter and without loss of generality one can take this single discontinuity at end point of interval of integration. Start by proving that if $g$ is bounded on $[a, b] $ and continuous on $(a, b] $ then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $.